# Convergence of a series with terms

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I am trying to find for what value is this this series convergent for:

$$1/3 -1/6 + 1/18  - 1/72 .....$$

Does it have a relation with exponential function?

Comment: Would you mind making the actual pattern explicit?

Comment: Try taking a factor $1/3$ out ...

Answer (score 2):

$$1/3 -1/6 + 1/18  - 1/72 .....=\frac{1}{3}(1-\frac{1}{2!}+\frac{1}{3!}-\frac{1}{4!}+....)=\frac{1-e^{-1}}{3}$$

Comment: @MarkBennet Thanks,I have corrected it